# What is the container used in the App Drawsomething to select the Colour?

Tags: android, slider, containers

I was working on an android app that lets you select a colour from a series of colour swatches. I was wondering what container is being used in the app "Draw Something" where the user can slide their finger over the paint swatches, and it moves the paint swatches over to show the rest of the colours that were previously off the screen.

If you haven't used the app, here is their website that has a screen cap of what the app looks like: http://omgpop.com/drawsomething

Any suggestions or comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it would be a special tool but its just a scroll view